# How to use Emacs and CEDET with SCons?

Tags: c++, emacs, scons, cedet, emacs-semantic

How to integrate SCons and emacs + cedet without breaking semantic and auto-complete?

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive?  How does what you have tried previously break semantic and auto-complete?  I'm unsure of how SCons would even affect those.

Comment: For example, I tried to set compile-command to scons. It breaks semantic and auto-complete, because semantic (and auto-complete) uses EDE to get information about, for example, include paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there exists SCons integration for cedet.
However, it is easy to set up an EDE project manually.

An lisp-snippet for a C++-project is given below.

```
(ede-cpp-root-project "myProject"
           :name "myProject"
           :file "my_project.txt"
           :include-path '("myproject/include")
           :system-include-path '("/usr/include/c++/4.5.1"
                                  "/usr/include/"))
```